# Creating a function that will combine varchar text from two fields on the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

My task is to create a function that concatenates the first name and last name from two fields found on the same table.

Table "**cust**":

| cus_id | f_name | l_name | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | Daniels | jack.daniels@google.com |
| 2 | Jose | Quervo | jose.quervo@yahoo.com |
| 5 | Jim | Beam | jim.beam@protonmail.com |

And here is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_concat(f_name character varying, l_name character varying)
RETURNS character varying
AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF cust.f_name IS NULL AND cust.l_name IS NULL THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    ELSEIF cust.f_name IS NULL AND cust.l_name IS NOT NULL THEN
        RETURN cust.l_name;
    ELSEIF cust.f_name IS NOT NULL AND cust.l_name IS NULL THEN
        RETURN cust.f_name;
    ELSE
        RETURN CONCAT(cust.f_name, ' ', cust.l_name);
    END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I run that code I get no errors and the function is successfully created in the functions table. Here is the query that I have used to test that newly created function:

```
SELECT * FROM fn_concat(f_name, l_name);
```

This is what my newly created function and test query should be returning:

Table "**cust**":

| cus_id | fn_concat | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack Daniels | jack.daniels@google.com |
| 2 | Jose Quervo | jose.quervo@yahoo.com |
| 5 | Jim Beam | jim.beam@protonmail.com |

But instead, I get an error, and here is that error:

```
ERROR: column "f_name" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM fn_concat(f_name, l_name); 
      ^ 
    
SQL state: 42703 
Character: 30
```

Thank you very much for any help that is offered.

Comment: Remove the `cust.` prefixes in the function body and `select *, fn_concat(f_name, l_name) from cust;` Or you can simply `select *, trim(concat(f_name, ' ', l_name)) from cust;`

Comment: How would I alter the create function statement to add that?

Comment: I have to use the Create or Replace function here so whatever solution you come up with has to fall within that. I understand there are easier ways to achieve a concatenation but that is not what the assignment calls for.

Comment: This right here: Remove the cust. prefixes in the function body and select *, fn_concat(f_name, l_name) from cust;  ... That did the trick. Freaking awesome but grrrr why didn't I see that. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the function

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_concat(arg_f_name text, arg_l_name text)
RETURNS text as
$$
  select trim(concat(arg_f_name, ' ', arg_l_name));
$$ language SQL;
```

Then call it like this

```sql
select *, fn_concat(f_name, l_name) from cust;
```

Answer (score 2):

The function call needs to be part of the SELECT list:

```
select cus_id, fn_concat(f_name, l_name), email
from cust
```

Btw: there is already a function that does exactly what you want: `concat_ws()`

```
select cus_id, concat_ws(' ', f_name, l_name), email
from cust
```